# Uniform convergence $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}\ln \frac{x}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Uniform convergence $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}\ln \frac{x}{n}$ on $E$ and $G$,  $E = (0,2), G = (0, +\infty)$

I have
$x \in E:$

$$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}(\ln x - \ln n)$$ $\lim_\limits {n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ and $$\lim_\limits {n \to \infty} \sup|\frac{x}{n}(\ln x - \ln n)| = \lim_\limits {n \to \infty} \sup|\frac{2}{n}(\ln 2 - \ln n)| =  0$$
So there is uniform convergence on $E$

Am I right?

What to do with $G$? Can I say that $\lim_\limits {n \to \infty} \sup|\frac{x}{n}(\ln x - \ln n)| = 0$, because we fix $x$?

Comment: No, the $\sup$ in $\lim \sup$ is taken over all $x\in G$ so you cannot fix it

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Is it interesting? we have 0 in lim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sup_{x\in G}f_n(x)\ge \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(n^2)=+\infty$$